# disable mouse over event in mobile view

Tags: jquery, mouseover

Im redesigning a ecommerce site which has mouseover event for showing shopping cart items . im not familiar with jquery or javascript. Initially its in display:none so when i hover then jquery come into act(display:block). Now i want to disable that mouse over event in mobile view. anybody can help ?

Here is the script used

```
        window['$cartItems'] = [];
    $(".carts").mouseover(function(){
      if(window['$cartItems'].length===0){
    $.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=common/header/getProducts',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
  var data=json.items;
  window['$cartItems'] = data;
  var html=''; 

     if(Object.keys(data).length==0)

      {     


    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {

    console.log("find");

        $('p#empt').html('Your shopping cart is empty');
        $('.cart-info').hide();
        $('p#empt').show();

          }

      } 
      else 
      {

        $('p#empt').hide();
      $('.cart-info').show();

    $.each(data,function(i,ele){


          html+='<tr style="height: 30px !important;width:400px;position:absolute;top: 34px;right: 166px;z-index: 99999; background-color:#FFFFFF; display:none"">'
                  +'<td colspan="6" style="border:none;">'
                  +'<image src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/reorder.png" alt="" title="" style="float:left;"  />'
                  +'<span style="float:left;line-height:18px; margin-left:10px;">'
                      +'<small></small>'
                  +'</td>'
                +'</tr>'
            +'<tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #f4f4f4; height: 30px !important;">'

            +'<td class="name text-center">'
            +'<small>'+ele.name+'</small>'

             +'</td>'
            +'<td class="quantity text-center">'

            +'<small>'+ele.quantity+'</small>'

             +'</td>'
            +'<td class="total text-center"><small>'+ele.total+'</small></td>'
            +'<td class="text-center">'
            + '<a href="http://www.cronaz.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove='+ele.key+'">'
            +'<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/remove.png" alt="" width="15" height="15" title="Remove" /></a>'
            +'</td>'
          +'</tr>';
          });
         $('#cartitems').html(html); 

  }

  }
   });
    }
    $(".minicart").css("display","block");  

    });




            $(".carts").mouseleave(function(e) {
                $(".minicart").css("display","none"); 
             });
```

here is php code

```
<li class="carts">
                                        <a title="<?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?>" href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart cart-icon"><span class="count newton" id="cart-total"><?php // echo count($this->cart->getProducts());?></span></span></a>
                                        <div class="minicart">
                                            <p id="empt"></p>
                                            <?php $products=$this->cart->getProducts(); ?>
                                            <div class="cart-info" style="display:none;" >
                                                <table class="table-responsive" width="100%">
                                                    <thead bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
                                                        <tr style="height: 30px !important;">
                                                            <td class="name text-center"><b><small>Product Name</small></b></td>
                                                            <td class="quantity text-center"><b><small>Quantity</small></b></td>
                                                            <!--<td class="price text-center fs14"><b><strong>Unit Price</strong></b></td>-->
                                                            <td class="total text-center"><b><small>Total</small></b></td>
                                                            <td class="total text-center"><b><small>Remove</small></b></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody id="cartitems">
                                                        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                                                        <?php if($product['recurring']): ?>
                                                        <tr style="height: 30px !important;">
                                                            <td colspan="6" style="border:none;">
                                                                <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/reorder.png" alt="" title="" style="float:left;"  />
                                                                <span style="float:left;line-height:18px; margin-left:10px;"> 
                                                                <small><?php echo $text_recurring_item ?></small>
                                                                <?php echo $product['profile_description'] ?>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                        <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #f4f4f4; height: 30px !important;">
                                                            <td class="name text-center">
                                                                <small><?php echo $product['name']; ?></small>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <!-- <td class="model text-center product-name"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>-->
                                                            <td class="quantity text-center">
                                                                <small><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></small>
                                                                <!-- <input type="text" readonly name="quantity[<?php echo $product['key']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" size="1" />-->
                                                                <!--&nbsp;
                                                                    <input type="image" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/update.png" alt="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" />-->
                                                            </td>
                                                            <!--<td class="price text-center"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>-->
                                                            <td class="total text-center"><small><?php echo $product['total']; ?></small></td>
                                                            <td class="text-center"> <a href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER .'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove='.$product['key'] ?>">
                                                                <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/remove.png" alt="" width="10" height="10" title="Remove" /></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't disable the onmouseover event. You just check your port view size when that event is triggered. 
In your code inside the `$(".carts").mouseover(function(){` you have to enclose everything inside an if statement that checks the size of your port view.

```
$(".carts").mouseover(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 768){
        //put all your code here...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if that was your question, but I see that you almost had it.

Comment: ya elijah thanks. Sorry it works fine for first window load but when i resize > 768 (2nd second time)  and come again to mobile view ...its not working

Comment: I would have to see your code, but if it works the first time, and it is not working on resize, that means that window.innerWidth is not being updated with the right size. If you can share your jquery and html code in a plunker it would be easier to debug.

Comment: its an opencart site so im doing in localhost ... is there alternative ?

Comment: My question is simple .. if some div is hidden already and if mouseover that it will display:block ,,, how i can disable that "already hidden div" to not shown in responsive using jquery/js ?